# The variables for my Job model is not showing

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created a Job model that contains Member and Manager info. It looks great imo. I created a class based view that translates the job if the user has one. Right now it's not showing. It just shows as a blank with an empty image file. I don't know what I did wrong or if I mistakenly used the wrong variables in the html file.

Here's my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, CreateView
from .models import Job
from profiles.models import User
# Create your views here.

class jobs(ListView):
    model = Job
    template_name = 'users/user_jobs.html'
    context_object_name = 'jobs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Job.objects.filter(member__member=self.request.user)


class createjob (CreateView):
    model = Job
    fields = ['member','title', 'description', 'file'
```

My Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from profiles.models import User
# Create your models here.

class Points (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

class Profile (models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png',upload_to='profile_pics')


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username}Profile'


class Manager (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Member (models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    manager = models.ForeignKey(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Job (models.Model):
    manager = models.OneToOneField(Manager, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    member = models.OneToOneField(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=False, null=False)
    description = models.TextField()
    datePosted = models.DateTimeField (auto_now = True)
    file = models.FileField(null=True, blank=True,upload_to='job_files')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

And user_jobs.html:

```
{% extends "profiles/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <img class="rounded-circle article-img"src="{{ jobs.manager.profile.image.url}}">
          <div class="media-body">

            <div class="article-metadata">
              <a class="mr-2" href="#">{{ objects.job.Manager }}</a>
              <small class="text-muted">{{jobs.datePosted|date:"F d, Y" }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2><a class="article-title" href="#">{{ jobs.title }}</a></h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ jobs.description }}</p>
          </div>
        </article>
    {% if is_paginated %}
      {% if page_obj.has_previous %}

      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page=1"> First</a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page={{ page_obj.previous_page_number }}"> Previous</a>

      {% endif %}

      {% for num in page_obj.paginator.page_range %}
          {% if page_obj.number == num %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a>
          {% elif num > page.obj.number|add:'-3' or num < page.obj.number|add:'3' %}
            <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a> 
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

      {% if page_obj.has_next %}

      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page={{ page_obj.next_page_number }}"> Next </a>
      <a class="btn btn-outline-info mb-4"href="?page={{ page_obj.paginator.num_pages }}"> Last </a>

      {% endif %}

    {%endif%}
{% endblock content %}
```

TIA for the help guys.

Answer (score 1):

you have to loop through the object list output in your list template to see the out put

```
{% for object in jobs %}
 {{ object.title }}
{% endfor %}
```